# Assign "Enter" key press to submit form in DotNetNuke

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect, dotnetnuke, keypress

After extensive research on the internet I can't find a way to get my DNN module to virtually click the "Search" button and stay there, because after doing what I want somehow DNN hijacks my keypress and redirects to the Home page of the portal.

Even in the production environment it redirects to the local development environment. I don't have full knowledge of how the portal is configured because I "inherited" it, but I neither know where to search...

Any tips on this?

BTW, my code is the following and works correctly before DNN redirects :

```
  $("input").keypress(function (event) {
       if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#<%=lbtnBuscar.ClientID%>").click();
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer by myself. To protect the application to redirect it's necessary to use this line of code:

//13 is the ASCII code of Enter key

ClientAPI.RegisterKeyCapture(pnContainer, btnSearch, 13);

The javascript I used is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## using javscript button click

```
 $("input").keypress(function (event) {
       if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("<%=lbtnBuscar.ClientID%>").click(); // Click on the Button
       }
  });
```

## if you wany use exsisting code

```
 $("input").keypress(function (event) {
       if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#'+'<%=lbtnBuscar.ClientID%>').click();
       }
  });
```

You are missing single quot, try this it will work. And if click on lbtnBuscar  it does postback call, stop that using usersubmit=false; on button.

Comment: The problem wasn't on the postback generated by the button click, as I was expecting it and it worked, but the second postback generated form the DNN framework which made my web to redirect to the main page (I still don't know why). Thanks for your reply anyway :)